# Mirroring content from Android device to Television without Chromecast

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, television, screen-mirroring

Besides buying the Google Chromecast HDMI stick, is there a way to mirror the content from an Android KitKat device to a "dumb" (i.e. not "smart") HDMI Television?

Solutions using Roku, Amazon Fire Stick, Blu-Ray players, or other devices are welcome.

The simpler, the better.

Comment: If you have a TV with Miracast, you can cast your phone to the TV without any 3rd party hardware.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil Thanks, but it's a "dumb" TV and not a "smart" TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use [Amazon Fire TV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U3FPN4U) and the [Amazon Fire Stick](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GDQ0RMG) and it works fine. The [Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/wireless-display-adapter) is supposed to work with Android devices as well.

How to use display mirroring on the Fire TV and Stick (from Amazon's website):

> To quickly start display mirroring, on your Amazon Fire TV remote
>   press and hold the Home button and select Mirroring. Then connect your
>   compatible device. Swipe down from the top of the screen to open Quick
>   Settings, and then tap Settings. Tap Display & Sounds, and then tap
>   Display Mirroring.

Comment: How does it work with Fire TV?  How do you initiate the mirroring from the other Android device?  Does it not work with the Fire Stick, or have you just not tried it?  Thanks!

Comment: From Amazon's website: "Mirror your tablet or phone on your HDTV
Share whatever is on your screen—including movies, TV shows, music, and photos—from your compatible tablet or phone with everyone in your living room using display mirroring. What you see on your Fire OS or Android device is exactly what you’ll see on your big screen. Includes support for devices from Motorola, LG, and Google without any additional apps or software." Same description for both the Fire TV and Stick, but only the Fire TV supports Mirracast for Windows. Android [should] work with both Fire TV and Stick.

Comment: I've only used it on my Fire TV so far (I do have both Fire TV and Stick but haven't had a need to cast to the Fire Stick yet) and it isn't the most straightforward procedure (although not too difficult). Here is the tip, again, from Amazon's website: "To quickly start display mirroring, on your Amazon Fire TV remote press and hold the Home button and select Mirroring. Then connect your compatible device. Swipe down from the top of the screen to open Quick Settings, and then tap Settings. Tap Display & Sounds, and then tap Display Mirroring."

Comment: Thanks for the info.  So how does it actually work?  Is there an app you run on the other device to transmit the data to the Fire TV/Stick?

Comment: According to Amazon, most Android 4.2 and higher devices support Miracast. Check your device's specs to make sure.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - I'll try this on the Fire Stick when I get home tonight and report back. I know the Stick is much less expensive than the TV box, so it would be the ideal unit if it does work.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - I just tested screen mirroring with the Amazon Fire Stick and my Galaxy S3- it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the details, testing, and research!

Comment: Just a warning about the Amazon Fire Stick:  My second one has stopped working after a year, and Amazon does not provide any warranty whatsoever for devices over a year old.